# search for a value in pandas dataframe in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

for the input such as `name AARTIIND`  and `ltp 1014`
I want output as `url` corresponding to lower bound of the ltp,

in this case
`https: // kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AARTIIND21JUN1020CE/13192450`

I am trying to write function to do this, I am stuck here, unable to think what should be
the searching condition which will return correct url

```
def find_url(name,ltp,df):
    return(df.iloc[df.index == name, ???)


name        strike      url
AARTIIND    1000    https: // kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AARTIIND21JUN1000CE/13190658
AARTIIND    1020    https: // kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AARTIIND21JUN1020CE/13192450
AARTIIND    1040    https: // kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AARTIIND21JUN1040CE/13201410
AARTIIND    1060    https: // kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AARTIIND21JUN1060CE/13202434
```

how can I get the required result?

Comment: The lower bound of `ltp` (1014) shouldn't be 1000 rather than 1020? Or maybe you want the upper bound or the closest value.

Comment: i want whichever is closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the closest value, subtract `ltp` to `strike` and compute the absolute value. The lowest value is the closest.

Try this:

```
def find_url(name, ltp, df):
    df1 = df.loc[df["name"] == name]
    return df1.loc[df1["strike"].sub(ltp).abs().idxmin(), "url"]

url = find_url("AARTIIND", 1014, df)
```

```
>>> url
'https: // kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/AARTIIND21JUN1020CE/13192450'
```

**Edit**:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'df["strike"]': df["strike"],
                  ".sub(ltp)": df["strike"].sub(ltp),
                  ".abs()": df["strike"].sub(ltp).abs()})

   df["strike"]  .sub(ltp)  .abs()
0          1000        -14      14
1          1020          6       6  # idxmin() return 1 (6 == the lowest value)
2          1040         26      26
3          1060         46      46
```

Comment: got this error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: The data type of your `strike` column is not numeric? Please provide `df.info()`.

Comment: when i print `dtypes` i get strike as object

Comment: You need to convert to numeric. Try `df.astype({"strike": int})`

Comment: error : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'`

Comment: I suspected it a little. You need to clean `strike` column before casting it to numeric. After that, the function is going to work, I promise :-)

Comment: it did work :)  can you please explain me this part  `.sub(ltp).abs().idxmin()`

Comment: `sub` for subtract, `abs` for absolute, `idxmin` to get the index of the lowest value (i.e. the closest of `ltp`). See the first line of my answer.